# Mapping of values to output in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot

Below is the controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/viewemp")  
public ModelAndView viewemp(ModelAndView model){  
    List<Employee> list=new ArrayList<Employee>();  
    list.add(new 
Employee("Rahul","abc@gmail.com","9985213655","Hyderabad",new 
java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis())));
           model.addObject("list",list);
    model.setViewName("viewemp"); 
    return model;
}
```

Below is the HTML:

```
<table border="2" width="70%" cellpadding="2">  
<tr><th>Name</th><th>Email</th><th>Contact</th><th>City</th> 
<th>Created_On</th></tr>  

<c:forEach var="emp" items="${list}">   
<tr>  
<td>${emp.Name}</td>  
<td>${emp.Email}</td>  
<td>${emp.Contact}</td>  
<td>${emp.City}</td>
<td>${emp.date}</td>   
</tr>  
</c:forEach>  
</table>
```

**My question is**: how to bind the values that are in the list(in the controller) to the output Html page. Currently upon running the code, the headers are obviously coming fine but the data in the list comes as: ${emp.Name} ${emp.Email} ${emp.Contact} ${emp.City} ${emp.date}  and the actual value is not being shown.

Also

If i make the output page as JSP, I am getting below exception:

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "viewemp", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

**My Question is**: How to make spring boot application recognize JSP pages?

Comment: Do you want to use Thymeleaf or JSP? Right now you have JSP syntax, but the exception you get indicates that you're using Thymeleaf, and not JSPs. Voting to close this question as unclear at this moment. Additionally to that, show us the structure of the `Employee` class.

Comment: **I want to use JSP. But also can I put thymeleaf and jsp dependencies both in pom? if yes, then how?.. also the employee class is nothing but a bean class with a constructor and setter getter methods.**

Comment: Never tried to put both on the classpath. As far as I know, Spring will detect and use one. And your employee class could be a bean class, but considering that you start with capital letters for all properties in your JSP, makes me wonder if you did the same thing in your `Employee` class. (Even though general conventions in the Java community tell you to use lowercase letters for properties)